# How to Docker task schedule? An alternate option for Windows task scheduler

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, cron, dockerfile

I am currently executing an exe file using windows task scheduler. I would like to run my exe file in docker container. Though I could think of running my exe file in docker, I am not sure how to schedule the run as it was achieved through windows task scheduler.

Please advise on how to schedule and run the .exe file in docker..

Note: Helm is what I use for deployment. So I cannot use docker-compose.yaml file.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for a Kubernetes [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)?

Comment: You should definetly consider using CronJob as suggested above, check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-cron-job) as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @David Maze rightly pointed out, you might be interested in [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cronjob).

We can find in the [CronJob documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/):

> CronJobs are useful for creating periodic and recurring tasks, like running backups or sending emails. CronJobs can also schedule individual tasks for a specific time, such as scheduling a Job for when your cluster is likely to be idle.

You can use a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cronjob) to run [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) on a time-based schedule, it's similar to Cron tasks on a Linux or UNIX system.

---

I'll create a simple example from scratch to illustrate how it works.

You typically create a container image of your application and push it to a registry before referring to it in a `CronJob`.
I'm not sure if you have a docker image already built, so I'll create one too.

Suppose I have a `job.py` Python script and want to "package" it as a docker image:

```
$ cat job.py
print("Starting job...")
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(i)

print("Done")
```

Docker can build images automatically by reading the instructions from a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).
I have a single Python script, so I will use the `python:3` image as the base image:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY job.py .

CMD [ "python", "./job.py" ]
```

After creating a Dockerfile we can use the [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) command to build Docker image and [docker push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/)
to share this image to the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) registry or to a self-hosted one.
**NOTE:** I'm using Docker Hub in this example.

```
### docker build -t <hub-user>/<repo-name>[:<tag>]
$ docker build -t zyrafywchodzadoszafy/cronjob:latest .
...
Successfully built cc46cde8fcdd
Successfully tagged zyrafywchodzadoszafy/cronjob:latest

### docker push <hub-user>/<repo-name>:<tag>
$ docker push zyrafywchodzadoszafy/cronjob:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/zyrafywchodzadoszafy/cronjob]
adabca8949d9: Pushed
a1e07bb90a13: Pushed
...

$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                     TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
zyrafywchodzadoszafy/cronjob   latest    cc46cde8fcdd   14 minutes ago   885MB
```

We can quickly make sure that everything is working by running this docker image:

```
$ docker run -it --rm zyrafywchodzadoszafy/cronjob:latest
Starting job...
1
2
3
4
5
Done
```

Now it's time to create a `CronJob`:

```
$ cat cronjob.yml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cronjob-test
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: cronjob-test
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: zyrafywchodzadoszafy/cronjob:latest
            name: cronjob-test
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *'

$ kubectl apply -f cronjob.yml
cronjob.batch/cronjob-test created

$ kubectl get cronjob cronjob-test
NAME           SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
cronjob-test   */1 * * * *   False     1        10s             36s
```

In the example above, `cronjob-test` `CronJob` runs the `job.py` Python script every minute.

Finally, to see if it works as expected, let's take a look at the `Pods` spawned by the `cronjob-test`  `CronJob`:

```
$ kubectl get pod
NAME                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
cronjob-test-1618581120-vmqtc   0/1     Completed   0          2m37s
cronjob-test-1618581180-nqqsd   0/1     Completed   0          97s
cronjob-test-1618581240-vhrhm   0/1     Completed   0          37s

$ kubectl logs -f cronjob-test-1618581120-vmqtc
Starting job...
1
2
3
4
5
Done
```

Much more information on specific configuration options can be found in the [CronJob documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).